# Get ip address and pass to Apollo client before react native renders (expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, apollo-client

in my app.js I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import * as Network from 'expo-network';
```

Per [Apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/) I am assigning a uri to httpLink. Currently the uri is static but I would like this uri to be dynamic and update before the app renders.

```
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: `http://192.168.1.165:5000/graphql`,
  });

  // get headers
  const authLink = setContext( async (_, { headers }) => {
   // return headers
   ...
});

// create apollo client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Finally rendering the app and passing client to Apollo:

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <SomeModule>
      </SomeModule>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};
```

I'm attempting to use Expo to get the client IP address. The [expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/network/) give a limited example of getting the ip address which I've interpreted to mean something like:

```
async function getLocalIPAddress() {
  const ipAddress = await Network.getIpAddressAsync();
  // do something
}
```

**How should I invoke the function to get the IP address before export default is invoked?**